# Threads in Java getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading, simulation, interrupt

I'm just trying to call a thread in java. I want to check if the thread is interrupted or not. The thread is defined in class "Scheduler". Here's the code:

```
        if (flag == true) 
        {
        thread = new Scheduler();
        thread.start();
        } 

        else 
        {
        thread.interrupt();
        }

        public void run() 
        {
            while (thread.isInterrupted() != true) // Here i get a NPE...
           { 
             //....
           }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide larger code snippet. It is not obvious where the field `thread` is defined etc.

Comment: a complete stacktrace of the exception and more code will be useful.

Comment: Please stop writing `(booleanCondition != true)`. Every time you do that, a baby kitten cries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the run() code snippet from your Scheduler ? In the run why do you have thread.isInterrupted() ? instead use

```
Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()
```

Also would be good to see the constructor and where the thread variable is declared

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the `NullPointerException` is probably because that variable isn't initialized, due to `flag` being false in the `if` statement, but I don't think that is the root of the problem here.

If you want to check if the called thread is interrupted, you should use

```
while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
```

In your snippet it looks like you are testing another `Scheduler` object instead.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, since flag is a boolean, you can simply write:

```
  if (flag) 
    {
        thread = new Scheduler();
        thread.start();
    } 

 else 
    {
        thread.interrupt();
    }
```

I believe that your issue is that flag evaluates to false, and you end up calling `isInterrupted()` on a null object.  It's also quite possible that you're referring to an entirely different thread than you think you are.  It's not clear which object you're referring to--you need to post more code.

Also:

```
while (!thread.isInterrupted()) // isInterrupted() returns a boolean, you don't need != true
   { 
             //....
   }
```

Comment: If flag is `false` NPE is expected when calling `thread.interrupt();`. Moreover in this case the thread is not created and therefore its `run()` method is not executed.

Comment: Yeah, I was really confused about that, too.  My assumption was that he hasn't tested that part of the code yet or somewhere in the code we don't have is something along the lines of `if(!flag)` initialize thread.